# Aiuto con la punteggiatura

Tags: punctuation

Ciao! sto sistemando delle sbobine di clinica chirurgica. Vorrei sapere se la punteggiatura è corretta in questo paragrafo.

> Il power color ha un solo colore e non gli interessa la direzione, ma l’entità del flusso.  Quindi è tutto orientato nell’identificare la presenza del movimento. È molto sensibile, mentre il color doppler è un pochino meno sensibile. Però dà la direzione del flusso, che vediamo qui come un **aspetto a divieto di sosta**, che è **tipico di scansione trasversale di un flusso turbolento**, perché sta girando in senso orario: guardando il paziente dai piedi verso la testa in traversale il flusso va in senso orario ed è un flusso totalmente turbolento.  Questo ci fa capire perché l’Aneurisma non è una patologia stabile, ma una patologia in accrescimento, in modifica constante giorno per giorno.

Comment: Non conosco l'argomento di cui si sta parlando, ma “aneurisma” è un nome comune e quindi va in minuscolo (come “punteggiatura”).

Comment: Per l’andamento dell’italiano, mi sembra che il testo, nella parte iniziale, sia un po’ troppo spezzettato. In particolare, invece del punto userei il punto e virgola prima di «Quindi» nella prima riga.

Comment: Potresti scrivere una risposta, @Benedetta?

Comment: Va bene, @Charo!

Comment: mi sembra di notare dei refusi "guardando il paziente dia piedi verso la testa in traversale" --> "guardando il paziente dai piedi verso la testa in trasversale"

Answer (score 3):

Senza considerare le differenze tra scritto e parlato e visto che la domanda è solo sulla punteggiatura, direi che, per l’andamento dell’italiano, il testo, nella parte iniziale, è un po’ troppo spezzettato. In particolare, invece del punto userei il punto e virgola prima di «Quindi» nella prima riga.

Inoltre, come suggerito da @DaG nei commenti, la parola «aneurisma» va con l’iniziale minuscola.